# Json representation not showing for newly added nested components

Tags: angular

Am creating a nested component inside another component, where am two-way binding the values of newly added fields Using JSON pipe in view, am not able to get the values as it is added dynamically

here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4TF8gFkZ6g6RSScmvHJ9?p=preview) link, if you click on *Add another address +* link it will add two fields street and postcode, inside that there will be an add button, on click of that it will add DOB and Designation field, if you type any values it won't be showing in the below JSON view

**Template**

```
<div [formGroup]="adressForm">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label>street</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="street">
        <small [hidden]="adressForm.controls.street.valid" class="text-danger">
            Street is required
        </small>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label>postcode</label> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="postcode">
    </div>
         <div class="margin-20">
          <a (click)="addextraField()" style="cursor: default">
            Add +
          </a>
        </div>

            <div formArrayName="extraspaces">
          <div *ngFor="let ext of adressForm.controls.extraspaces.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <span>Address {{i + 1}}</span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" *ngIf="adressForm.controls.extraspaces.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeAddress(i)"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
              <extrafield [extragroup]="adressForm.controls.extraspaces.controls[i]"></extrafield>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'address',
    templateUrl: 'address.component.html',
})
export class AddressComponent {
    @Input('group')
    public adressForm: FormGroup;
    private _fb: FormBuilder
    constructor(){}


    ngOnInit() {
        this.adressForm = this._fb.group({
            extraspaces: this._fb.array([])
        });

        // add address
        this.addextraField();

        /* subscribe to addresses value changes */
        // this.myForm.controls['addresses'].valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
        //   console.log(x);
        // })
    }


    initextraField() {
        return this._fb.group({
            dob: ['', Validators.required],
            designation: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }

    addextraField() {
        const control = <FormArray>this.adressForm.controls['extraspaces'];
        const addrCtrl = this.initextraField();

        control.push(addrCtrl);
    }

    // removeAddress(i: number) {
    //     const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['addresses'];
    //     control.removeAt(i);
    // }
}
```

please help me to resolve this issue, sorry if this is a duplicated one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to remember is to always build the complete form in the parent, no matter if there is a grandchild like in your case. This way the parent is aware of the whole form and the changes you make to the form. So there is actually a really easy solution. Remove the following in your `AddressComponent` OnInit, since the parent will not be aware of this formgroup:

```
this.adressForm = this._fb.group({
   street: [''],
   postcode: [''],
   extraspaces: this._fb.array([])
});
```

why it seems that it would recognize `street` and `postcode` from this code, actually it doesn't, it recognizes these two, because you have set them in the parent function `initAddress`. So therefore, just add `extraspaces: this._fb.array([])` in that function instead:

```
initAddress() {
    return this._fb.group({
        street: ['', Validators.required],
        postcode: [''],
        extraspaces: this._fb.array([])
    });
}
```

Here is your forked **[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/EMz0tN3RMpswW2ECPbNS?p=preview)**

**EDIT:**

I see you perhaps want to initialize also one of the innermost formgroup, then you could, then you could call function inside like so:

```
extraspaces: this._fb.array([this.initextraField()])
```

and use that same function (add it) in parent as you are using in `AddressComponent`, or then you manually set an empty form group inside that formArray.